# Why is it possible to iterate along a string?

Tags: python

I'm trying to understand why I can iterate along the string. What I see in the documentation is:

> One method needs to be defined for container objects to provide
>   iteration support:
>
> container.**__*iter*__**()
>
> Return an iterator object. The object is required
>   to support the iterator protocol described below. If a container
>   supports different types of iteration, additional methods can be
>   provided to specifically request iterators for those iteration types.
>   (An example of an object supporting multiple forms of iteration would
>   be a tree structure which supports both breadth-first and depth-first
>   traversal.) This method corresponds to the tp_iter slot of the type
>   structure for Python objects in the Python/C API.
>
> The iterator objects themselves are required to support the following
>   two methods, which together form the iterator protocol:
>
> iterator.**__*iter*__**()
>
> Return the iterator object itself. This is
>   required to allow both containers and iterators to be used with the
>   for and in statements. This method corresponds to the tp_iter slot of
>   the type structure for Python objects in the Python/C API.
>
> iterator.**next**()
>
> Return the next item from the container. If there are
>   no further items, raise the StopIteration exception. This method
>   corresponds to the tp_iternext slot of the type structure for Python
>   objects in the Python/C API.

But...

```
>>> dir('aa')
['__add__', '__class__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__doc__',
 '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__',
 '__getnewargs__', '__getslice__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__',
 '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__mod__', '__mul__', '__ne__',
 '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__rmod__',
 '__rmul__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__',
 '_formatter_field_name_split', '_formatter_parser', 'capitalize',
 'center', 'count', 'decode', 'encode', 'endswith', 'expandtabs',
 'find', 'format', 'index', 'isalnum', 'isalpha', 'isdigit', 'islower',
 'isspace', 'istitle', 'isupper', 'join', 'ljust', 'lower', 'lstrip',
 'partition', 'replace', 'rfind', 'rindex', 'rjust', 'rpartition',
 'rsplit', 'rstrip', 'split', 'splitlines', 'startswith', 'strip',
 'swapcase', 'title', 'translate', 'upper', 'zfill']
```

I don't see here any **__*iter*__**() or **next**(). So why does it work?

Comment: Although I doubt it's relevant here, don't put too much trust into `dir` in such cases. As the docs say: "Because dir() is supplied primarily as a convenience for use at an interactive prompt, it tries to supply an interesting set of names more than it tries to supply a rigorously or consistently defined set of names, and its detailed behavior may change across releases. For example, metaclass attributes are not in the result list when the argument is a class."

Comment: just to make things clear. `str` instances do implement `__iter__` as of python 3.2

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Iterators were new in Python 2.2.  The old method was the sequence protocol (implements `__getitem__` with 0-based indices) and still works.